# Fatal error: Call to undefined method with Wordnik API

Tags: php, api, wordnik

Not sure if this is an Wordnik API issue or just a php error on my part. Here is my current code:

```
require('./wordnik/Swagger.php');
require('./wordnik/WordsApi.php');

$myAPIKey = '00144cdc1140c4192780f08c3f608399234240dcb560d3e4b';
$client = new APIClient($myAPIKey, 'http://api.wordnik.com/v4');

$wordApi = new WordApi($client);
$input = new WordObject();
$input->includePartOfSpeech='noun';
$input->excludePartOfSpeech='affix,article,connjunction,preposition,abbreviation,suffix';
$input->hasDictionaryDef='true';
$input->minCorpusCount='10000';
$input->maxCorpusCount='null';
$input->minDictionaryCount='20';
$input->maxDictionaryCount=null;
$input->minLength='4';
$input->maxLength='20';

$random_word = $wordApi->getRandomWord($input); //THIS IS THE ERROR LINE
print $random_word->text;
```

and here is the error I get:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method WordApi::getRandomWord()

Any help is greatly appreciated. The error is happening on that line towards the bottom, just not sure why. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getRandomWord()` is defined in Word**s**Api (plural words).

- You have: WordApi
- You need: Word**s**Api

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: You're using `$wordApi = new WordApi($client);`, but you need Word***s***Api

Comment: Good thing I'm not a moron. Haha. Thank you very much.